# why do I get sample is too sparse to find TD using beanplot?

Tags: r, gplots, rsuite, beanplot

I am trying to draw a beanplot with the following code:

```
library(beanplot)

beanplot(df, col="#cccccc", names="plot-1", yaxt="n", overallline="median", ll=0.00001)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in bw.SJ(x, method = "dpi") : sample is too sparse to find TD
```

`dput(df)` data here: https://pastebin.com/fyCSmX6t

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`.

Comment: @Quinten shared the data.